# Change defaults of SSMS generating script

Tags: ssms

In Microsoft Sql Server Management Studio most of times I need a set of advanced settings when generating script. For example I need to set "**Script Drop and create**" to `true` and "**script extended properties**" to `false` etc. Is there a way or registery items to change the default settings for ever so I don't set them again any time?

Exactly I mean these settings:

```
Database > Tasks > Generate Scripts > Advanced Scripting Options
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of those settings can be found here:

`Tools -> Options -> SQL Server Object Explorer -> Scripting`

Of the two you specifically asked for, "Script extended properties" is present there. But "Script DROP and CREATE" is not. Perhaps it is called something different from one interface to the other, but I can't see anything that would correspond. It might be because Drop vs. Drop/Create vs. Create isn't so much an option as it is a "what do you want to do with this object?" decision.

(Tested in SSMS 17.9.1.)